# find all strings in a list that end with

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

For a given list:

```
list = ['enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history.xml.gz', 'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history.xml.gz-rss.xml',
'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history1.xml.gz', 'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history1.xml.gz-rss.xml', 
'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history10.xml.gz', 'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history10.xml.gz-rss.xml', 
'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history11.xml.gz', 'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history11.xml.gz-rss.xml', 
'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history12.xml.gz', 'enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history12.xml.gz-rss.xml']
```

I want to generate a new list that has all strings that end exactly in `.gz`

I tried these:

```
generated_list = [l for l in list if re.compile(r".gz$") in l]

generated_list = [file.endswith('.gz') for file in files]

generated_list = [file for file in files if '.gz' in file]
```

None of the above method seems to be working, second works but only produces boolean values.

Comment: `[file for file in files if file.endswith('gz')]`

Answer (score 0):

The right way to address this problem is to learn how list comprehension works.

```
generated_list = [file for file in files if file.endswith('.gz')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
generated_list = [ file for file in list if file.endswith(".gz")]
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.